# Read csv with opencsv

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

```
List<First> listfirst(String dir){    
        try {           
            List<First> list=new ArrayList<First>();                       
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(dir));
            String [] nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
             // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
            list.add(new First(nextLine[0], nextLine[1], nextLine[2],nextLine[3], nextLine[4],nextLine[5], nextLine[6], nextLine[7])); 
            }           
            return list;
        } catch (Exception e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

There are 1994 rows. But this code print only 388 rows.What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

This is what i would suggest a read should look like:

**Read file**

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReadProc;
import java.util.Arrays;

csv.read("example.csv", new CSVReadProc() {
    public void procRow(int rowIndex, String... values) {
        System.out.println(rowIndex + ": " + Arrays.asList(values));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to read the entire `CSV` , read it once and iterate over it as,

```
    List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();

      //Read CSV line by line and use the string array as you want
     for(String[] row : allRows){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
     }
   }
```

And also try to use the constructor of `CSVReader` with ,

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("input.csv"), ',', '"', 0);
// 0 refers the 1st line
```